# What's the preferred solution to other users writing my username wrong?

Tags: discussion, display-names, spelling

This is probably a weird and somewhat silly question, but recently, I've found that a couple of users have made the same typo in my username: Nzali instead of Nzall. If people accidentally make a typo in my username, what should I do? ignore it, make a comment asking them if they can fix it, or try to fix it myself? Assume it's the only issue with the answer (or question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the spelling of your name is specifically relevant to the question or answer (ie, the question or answer would be wrong or unusable due to the spelling error) then I'd suggest ignoring it and moving on.

The community is so large that you're going to be issuing corrections all the time - they (meaning the community of thousands or millions depending on the site) won't simply start to remember the correct spelling after a few months of casual reminders.

Any comments you might add to ask for a correction are going to be clutter.

If you have another good reason to edit the post, then go ahead and fix it if it's important to you, but if not then you're bumping the post and cluttering up the front page when nothing substantial has been added to the post.

So my advice is to ignore it and move on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. The capital I is occasionally mistaken for an L so people @Lain me or whatever ...

If I able to do so I will edit the question or answer to fix my name and leave an Edit Summary to that effect. If it's in a comment that I can't edit I just get on with my life.

Comment: If they spell your name wrong in a comment, its probably in an @ reference. At the point where your reading that comment, it probably doesnt matter, either.